# Access hardware features through mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, html

Is there a way to access hardware features (Ex: Bluetooth) through HTML5, javascript which runs on android native or mobile chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

Through plain HTML and javascript I dont think it is possible to access native device features like bluetooth.You can try using cross platform development tools for it.Phonegap or rhodes may help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can only access hardware if:

1. You are using phonegap, appcelerator or other mobile platform.
2. You are using firefox mobile phone.